# How to submit app for distribution, after testing on tesflight

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

I've uploaded 6 version for testing, & I kept increasing the build version. Now I wanted to upload for distribution & want to make it version 1 but I think uploading will fail, since it always expect build with higher version.

One more thing I was using Distribution profile for uploading Testflight build (Xcode was taking it automatically, I was not changing anything). And now for distribution am doing same, xcode selected Distribution Profile automatically. I've not change anything in build.setting or any other file which I was using for test build with internal testflight user.

Am I doing right steps?
And how I can make that build as 1.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't upload an app with a lower build number, it will always result in an iTunes Connect Error.

The build number is for your own use only, users will see the version number you specify in iTC and never the build number.

[Apple documentation on build numbers.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html)

Comment: Thanks but I've also changed version number in Xcode Target to 6 & build number 6. One more thing as far as I know you need to keep same version number in xcode which you've set there in itunes connect.

Answer (score 0):

you can change display version in iTunes